# Rails api controller doesn't inherit method from the parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Doing API for my first Rails project.
I have base class ApiController for all the APIs:

```
module Api
  class ApiController < ::ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
      @collection = resource_class.all
      render json: @collection.as_json(as_json_collection)
    end

    private

    def resource_class
      raise NotImplementedError
    end

    def as_json_collection
      {}
    end

  end
end
```

And I have child class UsersController:

```
module Api
  class UsersController < ApiController

    private

    def resource_class
      User
    end

    def resource_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
namespace :api do
    resources :users
end
```

Then I'm going to my_app/api/users I have error:

> The action 'index' could not be found for Api::UsersController

But then I changing UsersController writing it's own index class, everything works fine and I'm having all my Users in JSON format.
I've alrady tried to comment all private marks in both classes, but that doesn't help.
I don't want to write an API for every entity in my project and I'd like to avoid this problem in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
module Api
  class ApiController < ::ApplicationController

    def index
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: '"abc"' }
      end
    end
  end
end

module Api
  class UsersController < ApiController
  end
end
```

The URL was `http://localhost:3000/api/users.json`

So for you I suggest:

```
module Api
  class ApiController < ::ApplicationController

    def index
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json do
          @collection = resource_class.all
          render json: @collection.as_json(as_json_collection)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module Api
  class UsersController < ApiController
    def resource_class
      User
    end

    def resource_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did as you said. And It seems that now rails can see my index action, that's cool. But now I have ActionController::UnknownFormat error in line `respond_to do |format|` in ApiController class.

Comment: I edited my answer, because I forgot the `format.json`.  Make sure you have `.json` at the end of the URL.

Comment: I do not know if the `respond_to` was your problem, but I got my first example to work, so the inheritance works.  You will have to take it from the inheritance working and put the functional code back in.

Comment: That works now, thanks. I should remember adding `.json` at the URL if I use your example.

Answer (score 0):

Its supposed to be like this:

```
  class Api::ApiController < ApplicationController
```

and do not forget to remove extra `end`, end of the file!

```
#sample
- api(folder)
-- api_controller.rb   (Api::ApiController < ApplicationController)
-- users_controller.rb (Api::UsersController < Api::ApiController)

application_controller.rb
```

Comment: Also, you do not have `index` action in `users_controller`, create it !!!

Comment: Why should I add index action if I have it in the parent class? Still doesn't works

Comment: @Arty cuz this `my_app/api/users` asks users index method not parent.

Comment: if wanna make parent one: `get 'index' => 'api#index'`, and route `my_app/api/index`

Comment: @7urkm3n The way inheritance works, if the class doesn't have it, it should ask the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this my friend:
[rails routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

When you do this:

```
namespace :api do
    resources :users
end
```

rails creates CRUD routes automatically which means that `my_app/api/users` will translate to: `.../users#index`.

Do this to see your routes created by rails:

`rails routes` and for specific word (e.g. user): `rails routes | grep user`

**Seeing is believing ;)**